# How can a current mirror be adjusted to create a ratio between the reference and the output current?

Tags: transistors, current, current-source, current-mirror

I am working on a project were I need to pass a current through a load and a larger multiple through a different load. Hence if I pass 100mA through this load I need to pass approx 10A through the other load but it is important that the correlation between the two currents is strictly maintained. Does anyone has any ideas how this could be achieved?
Preferably I use a MOSFET however BJT can also be used.

Comment: It seems like what you want is a current amplifier (current controlled current source) more than a mirror.

Comment: *the correlation between the two currents is strictly maintained.* That is not a properly formulated design requirement as strictly, that's **impossible**. There will **ALWAYS** be some error. What you need to specify is how much error you can allow. And don't ask for "the best" or "as little error as possible". A proper answer would be 10 % or 0.1 %.

Comment: you are talking about a 100:1 current mirror, that would require… 101 transistors:D also: mirrors are handy on silicon, unless you use expensive matched discretes they are almost useless as precision. As in the answer the best way is amplifying with a booster output transistor.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a principal schematic to show you an idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f72xEN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Separately generated reference current (I<sub>ref</sub> above) drops a voltage across RS1, 1-Ohm resistor. In the beginning, the MOSFET, M1 is off. So the inverting input of the opamps sees ground through RS2. So the comparator's output starts to rise, and so does the drain current.

The drain (load) current drops a voltage across RS2, 10-mOhm resistor. Once this voltage hits the reference voltage, \$\mathrm{V_{ref}=I_{ref}\ RS1}\$, in other words the load current hits \$\mathrm{I_{ref}\cdot RS1 / RS2 = 100\ I_{ref} = 10A}\$, the comparator's output starts to decrease, so does the drain current. Once the drain current drops enough to make the comparator output high again the cycle begins afresh.

With the help of the negative feedback, the load current will be kept at \$\mathrm{I_{LOAD}=I_{ref}\cdot RS1 / RS2 = 100\ I_{ref}}\$.

NOTES:

- The M1 above is a randomly selected MOSFET (i.e. the schematic editor's default). You should put one according to your needs.
- This is a principal schematic. So you may need to do some adjustments (e.g. you don't have to use an LM324)

Comment: I suspect OP meant more traditional current mirror with two BJT, rather than op amp

Comment: @Maple true. But I went for an opamp-based solution because of this: `it is important that the correlation between the two currents is strictly maintained.` It's obvious that it's not simple to obtain an x100 ratio with traditional current mirrors. If there's a practical solution I'm eager to see.

Comment: Ah, I see. I admit, I posted a comment because I too was looking for simple generic solution with about 1:2 ratio some time ago. I used optocoupler in that case to get both isolation and proportion but the linearity suffered.

Comment: Yes for a x100 ratio the opamp will most likely be the best solution, especially at 10A, where you want low voltage drop on the sense resistor, which means you need a low offset component to sense voltage on it to minimize error. PS: the MOSFET adds an extra pole in the feedback loop that can make the opamp oscillate, so a compensation cap between OPA output and IN- is usually necessary.

Comment: @bobflux that's why I intentionally said "this is a principal schematic".